# Java Swing panels and graphics stopped displaying

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I'm new to Java Swing (and fairly new to Java in general) and I've been messing around with Swing for a while, but after making some changes my panels stopped displaying and I don't know why.

When using `isDisplayable()` on my JPanel object it returns `false`. After more investigation my program does not seem to display graphics at all.

Even a simple piece of code doesn't work for me anymore:

```
public class window extends JFrame {

        window(){

        setBounds(100,100,1200,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new window();

    }
```

I have no idea what I changed for this to happen, but all I get is a blank a completely blank window.

Any help is appreciated a lot!

Comment: 1) class names should start with an upper case character 2) by convention constructors are coded first in your class, not last.

Comment: My WiFi is currently down but I'll try to get a minimal example of my code up soon. And thanks for the tips camickr, I'll try to remember those in the future!

Comment: After some more investigation I've edited my example to what I think is the simplest it could get.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

See the code comments.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BlackWindow extends JFrame {

    BlackWindow(){
        setBounds(100,100,400,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // sets the frame black, not the content pane
        //setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BlackWindow();
    }
}
```

This example also speaks to a few general principles we follow when using Swing's `JFrame`:

1. Don't extend the `JFrame` class, just use an instance of one.
2. Don't do anything significant to the coloring or styling of a frame, instead color (for example) a `JPanel` and **add it** to the frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question: in a situation like this, how would I add my panel to the frame? And if you don't mind to explain, why should I not extend the JFrame class (I'd like to know so I don't make this mistake again)?

Comment: *"Quick question:"* Ooh. I know one of those: What is the meaning of life? Just 5 words and very quick to ask. The thing is, philosophers, theologians and psychoanalysts could argue the answer for millennia - while the nihilists argue it is an invalid question as it presumes life *has* a meaning. The reason I mention that, is that each of those questions is worthy of its own question thread. Have at it! Asking questions is free, but please put some (research and) effort into each one. 